# MS Graph API - Get access without a user - Verifying MS response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When using MS-Graph oauth flow ["Get Access without a user"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), Microsoft responds with a GET request of the following structure (from the example in the linked page):

```
GET https://localhost/myapp/permissions
?tenant=a8990e1f-ff32-408a-9f8e-78d3b9139b95
&state=12345
&admin_consent=True
```

Is there anyway to verify that the response came from Microsoft?

In our application we're using the `state` to link an internal tenant-id with the Microsoft tenant-id. If the above response can be forged, an adversary may link his own tenant-id to the victim's Microsoft tenant-id.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to check for this step (3) in the doc, because if the admin *didn't* consent, you would not be able to get an actual token for your app in step 4. However, you might be able to get the [Referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), if it's important to know which page the user came from to get back to your 'https://localhost' page.

Answer (score 0):

You generate something before the redirect, like a guid. Save it on the server, and use it to query the data from before the redirect.

See it as a temporary key that you can set and save in the server memory or in a database.

The state is something you specify before redirecting. And after the admin consent it’s returned to the browser.